# Javascript not being executed because of XSS protection

Tags: javascript, ajax, xss

I have an HTML form on a wordpress based site that allows users to see database records that match the inputs of the form. Using AJAX based on this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp I have a javascript that uses a GET on a php script on the server. however the javascript is not permitted to run by XSS protection the console output is as follows

```
The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'page' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header.
```

Is this caused by how my javascript is invoked?

Source:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(degreecourse, Interest, gradyear){
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  else{document.getElementById("info").innerHTML}="Error";
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/getcandidates.php?q=degreecourse=" + escape(degreecourse) + "&Interest=" + escape(Interest) + "&gradyear=" + escape(gradyear),true);
xmlhttp.send();
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Filter By:


<form >
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Degree Course:</td>
<td><select name="degreecourse" onchange = "showUser(document.getElementById('degreecourse').value, document.getElementById('Interest').value, document.getElementById('gradyear').value)">
<option>Any</option><option>Archaeology</option><option>Biochemistry</option><option>Biology</option><option>Biomedical Sciences</option><option>Chemistry</option><option>Computer Science</option><option>Economics</option><option>Education</option><option>Electronics</option><option>English</option><option>Environmental Studies</option><option>History</option><option>History of Art</option><option>Language and Linguistic Studies</option><option>Law</option><option>Management</option><option>Mathematics</option><option>Medicine</option><option>Music</option><option>Nursing, Midwifery and Healthcare</option><option>Philosophy</option><option>Physics</option><option>Politics</option><option>Politics, Economics and Philosophy</option><option>Psychology</option><option>Social Policy and Social Work</option><option>Social and Political Sciences</option><option>Sociology</option><option>Theatre, Film and Television</option></select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Interest:</td>
<td><select name="Interest" onchange = "showUser(document.getElementById('degreecourse').value, document.getElementById('Interest').value, document.getElementById('gradyear').value)">
<option>Any</option><option>Management</option><option>Marketing<option>Technical</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Graduating After:</td><td><input id="gradyear" type="number" value=2013 name="gradyear" onchange = "showUser(document.getElementById('degreecourse').value, document.getElementById('Interest').value, document.getElementById('gradyear').value)"/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
<br>
<div id="info"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The PHP file returns a HTML table as follows after connecting to the database.

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Degree Subject</th>
<th>Email Address</th>
<th>Graduating Year</th>
<th>Interest</th>
<th>CV</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Forname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Surname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['DegreeSubject'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['EmailAddress'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['GraduatingYear'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Interest'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><form action='www.yorkcommunityconsulting.co.uk/CVs/".$row['CVurl']."><input type='submit' value='See CV'></form></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: `because its source code was found within the request` ... What's the URL?

Comment: Do not use or link to tutorials from w3 schools, please. They are essentially junk.

Comment: http://www.yorkcommunityconsulting.co.uk/search-for-staff/ the problem may have been caused by the fact it was an unpublished draft on wordpress.

Comment: The problem is probably that the **response** to your AJAX request contains an embedded `<script>` tag.

Comment: @Pointy Ive updated the question with the response that will be generated by the php. there is no embedded script in there.

Comment: OK well it all depends on what exactly that "XSS Auditor" thing is.

Comment: chrome has started busting my balls over this recently, in lots of places where it should (and recently did) mind it's own business... im having to base64 until i can find a fix, since i can't config the server headers...

Answer (score 0):

1. The escape() function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5. Use encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent() instead. I'm not sure It'll get you where you want, but may solve at least part of your problem.
2. Have you tried using jQuery (GET/load) instead of plain JS to see if you get the same result ?
3. You have an `<option>` tag that is not not properly closed (see "Marketing")
4. I'm no JS guru but, didn't you have to close your "else" a bit later ? like after the: "Error"; instead of before the "=" sign ?

```
    else{document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="Error";}

    instead of

    else{document.getElementById("info").innerHTML}="Error";
```